# how to use a class in an activity? DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

From [Google Developer UI guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs)
You can accomplish a wide variety of dialog designs—including custom layouts and those described in the Dialogs design guide—by extending DialogFragment and creating a AlertDialog in the onCreateDialog() callback method.

For example, here's a basic AlertDialog that's managed within a DialogFragment:

What?

```
    public class ResetAll    extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {          
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.reset)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.reset2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // code
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // code
                    }
                });           
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Use here the Class?

```
 @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {        
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

       // USE HERE! DIALOG

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager().show(new ResetAll())` most likely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {        
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

       // USE HERE! DIALOG
       ResetAll dialog = new ResetAll();
       dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "restFragmentDialog");

// restFragmentDialog is a unique tag name that the system uses to save and restore the fragment state when necessary.
// The tag also allows you to get a handle to the fragment by calling findFragmentByTag().

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

From [Google UI link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs) mentioned on question.

**Showing a Dialog**

> When you want to show your dialog, create an instance of your
>   `DialogFragment` and call `show()`, passing the `FragmentManager` and a tag
>   name for the dialog fragment.
>
> You can get the `FragmentManager` by calling `getSupportFragmentManager()`
>   from the `FragmentActivity` or `getFragmentManager()` from a `Fragment`.